# Let Master Agent to know where the Docker is in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Well, I got a problem, to be more specific, it is related to docker, So when I run my Jenkins Pipeline, it cannot recognize any docker commands, and responds with `docker: command not found` when I'm trying to run it.

Just a Snippet of what I'm trying to achieve in Pipeline.

```
steps {
  sh "docker build ." // just example
}
```

My Pipeline for managing docker Images looks like this and Using Master Agent With `Docker Pipeline Plugin` and `Docker Plugin` installed as well.

What I'm trying to do there, is basically to build the Golang application Image, run some healthchecks, tag it and push to remote dockerhub repo..

```
// Pipeline that Builds / Tests / Deploys the new Version of the Image.
pipeline {

    agent { dockerfile {filename "Dockerfile" dir "."}}
    envinronment {
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS=credentials("DockerHub")
    }
    stages {

        stage("build"){
            steps{
                sh "echo 'Running Build Pipeline...'"
                sh "docker build . --name=new_versioned_image"
                sleep 10 
                sh "echo 'Docker Built Image Successfully! And Initial Tests Has been Passed. Going to the Testing Stage..'"
            }
        }

        stage("test"){
            steps{
                // checking for application health..
                load "./version_env.groovy"

                sh "echo 'Running Test Pipeline'"
                sh "echo 'Running Healtcheck Test...'"
                sh "Sleeping until the Application will be fully ready..."
                sleep 10    

                script {
                    final String url = "http://${env.APPLICATION_HOST}:${APPLICATION_PORT}"
                    final def (String response, int code) =
                    sh(script: "curl -X GET -f $url", returnStdout: true).trim().tokenize("\n")
            
                    if (code == 200) {sh "echo Application health State Is Okay... Running Deployment Stage.."}else{
                        echo "Application Responded with Failure."
                        error "Health Check Stage Failure."
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage("deployment"){

            steps {  
                load "./version_env.groovy"
                load "./JenkinsCredentials.groovy" // Create A File Called `JenkinsCredentials` and Put There Credentials for `withCredentials` Statement.
                
                sh "echo 'Running Deployment Pipeline Stage...'"
                sh "echo 'Tagging new Image Version'"

                withCredentials([
                    credentialsId: "DockerHub" at Jenkins Server...
                    usernameVariable: env.DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR, 
                    passwordVariable: env.DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW, 
                ]){
                    sh "docker login -u ${env.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME} -p ${env.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}"
                    sh "Logged In.. Into Docker."

                    sh "echo 'Tagging An Image'"
                    sh "docker tag new_versioned_image ${env.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY_LINK}:latest"
                    sh "echo 'Tagged... Pushing onto docker repo.'"

                    sh "docker push ${env.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY_LINK}:latest"

                    sh "docker tag new_store_application_image ${env.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME}:latest"
                    sh "echo 'Tagged Successfully.. Pushing Image On Docker Hub..'"
                    sh "echo 'Image has been Pushed Successfully! Pipeline Finished.'"
                }
            }
        }
        
        post {
            always {
                sh "Logging Out From Dockerhub..."
                sh "docker logout"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even After Plugins Installation, it does not seem to work.

Potential Solutions:

I Heard, that I need to specify the root of the docker installation directory in the `PATH` variable in the `master` agent. But How can I do that?

The second way is to run a Jenkins Slave Agent, then connect to it using `SSH`, install docker on that machine and run this Pipeline using this Agent, but this is way longer, so I would prefer to go with the first one...

My Initial Question is, `How to fix the issue "docker: command not found" in the Jenkins Pipeline` so, also expect for some more suggestions about this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. User Docker installation of your Host machine. For this, you can mount the Docker sock to your docker image. Typically this will look something like the one below. You have to pass the mounting args to your Agent. Refer [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#caching-data-for-containers) example.

```
 docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

2. Install Docker in the Container itself. Simply add the following to your Dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
```

Comment: am I need to add some permission stuff like `usermod -aG docker jenkins`for the Jenkins User in the Dockerfile ( second case ), or this is a final one?